# Locked Excel workbook

Tags: xlsxwriter

I'm encountering an issue with xlsxwriter.  I'm able to create the multiple sheet workbook, my python script executes without errors.  When I try opening the Worksheet Excel says it is in use by another user.  I can open it read only.   when I close out of Spyder is seems to release the workbook.  I have workbook.close() at end of script.  Not sure what else to do.  Any suggestions greatly appreciated.